# Generalizations of PERT diagrams

Tags: optimization, operations-research

Suppose that a small company wants to produce a set of toys in the shortest time. Each toy needs a number of operations (printing, painting, etc.) to be done by humans or machines following a given order. Moreover, the number of operations (and the needed time) can vary from one toy to the other, and each machine or human can do only some of the operations, but not all. Finally, there are more toys requiring a certain operation than machines/humans able to do it, and a machine/human can work at a given time on a single toy. I would be interested in minimizing the time necessary to produce the complete set. The first solution that comes to my mind is a PERT diagram. However, the PERT diagram does not allow e.g. alternative paths. I am aware of the existence of generalizations like M-PERT, etc. What do you suggest? Other possible alternatives not related to PERT would also be welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sounds like [job shop scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling)